# Powershell Script Not Executing Fully from C# Application

Tags: c#, powershell, csv, console

So I'm trying to run a Powershell script from C#

```
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\nameofuser\Desktop\script.ps1");

        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript(text);

            PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
            if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.Write("Error");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

This is the Script File

```
$username = "xxx"
$password = "xxx"
$server = "xxx"
$database = "xxx"
$currentuser = "xxx"
$homepath = "C:\Users\$currentuser\Desktop"

mkdir "$homepath\csvs"
mkdir "$homepath\csvs\$database"
$AttachmentPath = "$homepath\csvs\$database\name.csv"
$QueryFmt = "SELECT * FROM TEST"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -User $username -Password $password -ServerInstance $server - 
Database $database -Query $QueryFmt | Export-CSV $AttachmentPath
```

However, the script only runs up through to line mkdir "$homepath\csvs\$database" and then stops working. In other words, the query inside of the script is not executing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you confirm that running the script outside of C#, by itself, works?

Comment: Yep it works just fine

Comment: There should be an error output of some sort if it is failing at the Query. Did you perform any error handling?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a

```
Import-Module Sqlps
```

At the beginning of your powershell script and see if it's because your c# context does not have the sql module loaded during run time.

Comment: It seems to just hang up on the import now

Comment: Oddly enough it seems the script is actually hanging up by itself now with some connectivity issues that I fixed. It's working now so all the above code was correct. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enable PowerShell scripts to execute on your computer. Your C# is running but, by default, windows does not allow PowerShell to execute.

Start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as Administrator" option. Only members of the Administrators group on the computer can change the execution policy.

Enable running unsigned scripts by entering:
    **set-executionpolicy remotesigned**

This will allow running unsigned scripts that you write on your local computer and signed scripts from Internet.